# Google font not showing up in one section of the page

Tags: css, wordpress, google-font-api

I've used 'lobster two' here: http://www.blackcatcoding.co.uk/keepsakes

it works fine everywhere in firefox, but in every other browser it doesn't work in the header of the main section... not sure what's going on??

Comment: It works fine with me anyway in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
font-family: 'Lobster Two',cursive; //style.css ~ line 150
```

Change this to:

```
font-family: 'Lobster Two';
font-style:italic;
```

i guess that other browsers are confused with 'cursive'. :)

Checked in Chrome, and it works.